# Life of timer after we kill the activity

Tags: android, timer, android-activity

This is my first week with android and I want to ask a simple question of which I couldn't find anything relevant on google.

Does timer remain active after we kill activity or it simply ends with the activity? I mean what's the scope of timer if it's defined inside the activity?

```
new CountDownTimer(3900000, 5000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 if(db.getService(services.getServiceName()).toString().contains("Activated")){
                     cancel();
                 }
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 mTextField.setText("done!");
             }
          }.start();
```

EDIT : 
After trying/using count down timer for few times it's clear that it ends with the activity.

Answer (score 3):

No timer remain active. If you want to stop it use:

```
@Override
public void finish()
{
   killYourTimer();
   super.finish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it in a moment.

Comment: Didn't work it dies along with the activity as it's simply an object defined inside activity

Comment: Obviusly it can be garbage collected with the activity owner but with this code you can force the timer to finish.